# Pandas assign value in one column based on top 10 values in another column

Tags: pandas

I have a table:

```
     A   B   C  D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4
```

I would like to make a new column called 'flag' for the top 2 values in column D.

I've tried:

```
for i in df.D.nlargest(2):
    df.['flag']= 1
```

But that gets me:

```
    A    B   C  D  flag
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0   1
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1   1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5   1
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4   1
```

What I want is:

```
    A    B   C  D  flag
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0   0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1   0
2   NaN NaN NaN 5   1
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['flag'] = 0
df.loc[df.D.nlargest(2).index, 'flag'] = 1
```

Or:

```
df['flag'] = df.index.isin(df.D.nlargest(2).index).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
     A    B   C  D  flag
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0     0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1     0
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5     1
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4     1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df['flag']=df.D.sort_values().tail(2).eq(df.D).astype(int)
df
     A    B   C  D  flag
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0     0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1     0
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5     1
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4     1
```